# On page resize, page adding extra top in minus. it's not working.(Slider boomerang effect)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On page resize, page adding extra top in minus. it's not working.(Slider boomerang effect)

```
<https://codepen.io/GrandvincentMarion/pen/NaEELP>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *"page adding extra top in minus"*?

Comment: when you resize that demo.
I can see a white background.
with scrolling up